# Styling a table's td in [css]

Tags: css

I know this sounds pretty simple, but my table class has a space in-between it and it doesn't seem to be allowing me to modify the style using css.

**My html table is below:**

```html
<table class="shop_table order_details" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left;width: 20%;"><strong>Product</strong></th>
      <th style="text-align:left;width: 80%;"><strong>Digital Codes</strong></th>
      <td><button class="btn btn-copy-code" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#group-1" style="display: none;"><span class="text-code">Copy Code</span></button></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left;width: 20%;">Xbox $5 Code</td>
      <td style="text-align:left;width: 80%;"><span class="lic-key" id="group-2">BBBB-CCCC-AAAV</span><br></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-copy-code" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#group-2"><span class="text-code">Copy Code</span></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to modify the td that has BBBB-CCCC-AAAV inside of it to add a bottom border.

**My css I want to insert it for is below :**

```
table.shop_table order_details td {
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 8px;  
}
```

Instead of the above code, I need it to work for the 2 td's that have (BBBB-CCCC-AAAV) and the second showing (Copy Code).

The reason I want to change these 2 is becuase the borders are not being set for these.

Look in this image : [image here](https://gyazo.com/ef30c99b0cdf748ae0e7e2cedf656db5)

Comment: Looks like you want it around the entire tr, not the td as you specify above the CSS you want to use.

Comment: Okay yes. I've now removed the other borders. How would I go about adding a border for this whole tr ?

Comment: This could be difficult to answer if we're not able to see/know what other CSS may be at work on these elements.

Comment: Okay yes. I've now removed the other borders. How would I go about adding a border for this whole tr ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your example image, you actually want it around the entire table. Just target the table with your CSS directly.

```css
table {
  outline: thin solid;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<table class="shop_table order_details" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left;width: 20%;"><strong>Product</strong></th>
      <th style="text-align:left;width: 80%;"><strong>Digital Codes</strong></th>
      <td><button class="btn btn-copy-code" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#group-1" style="display: none;"><span class="text-code">Copy Code</span></button></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left;width: 20%;">Xbox $5 Code</td>
      <td style="text-align:left;width: 80%;"><span class="lic-key" id="group-2">BBBB-CCCC-AAAV</span><br></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-copy-code" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#group-2"><span class="text-code">Copy Code</span></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Adjust the CSS properties to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
td:nth-child(2) {
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 8px;
}
```

```html
<table class="shop_table order_details" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left;width: 20%;"><strong>Product</strong></th>
      <th style="text-align:left;width: 80%;"><strong>Digital Codes</strong></th>
      <td><button class="btn btn-copy-code" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#group-1" style="display: none;"><span class="text-code">Copy Code</span></button></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left;width: 20%;">Xbox $5 Code</td>
      <td style="text-align:left;width: 80%;"><span class="lic-key" id="group-2">BBBB-CCCC-AAAV</span><br></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-copy-code" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#group-2"><span class="text-code">Copy Code</span></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @BenZa Then you're going to need to get a lot more specific about what it is you're looking for, as it's not terribly clear.

Comment: I have updated my content. Please try to understand now.

Answer (score -1):

there's my little solution :

```
<table class="shop_table order_details" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align:left;width: 20%;"><strong>Product</strong></th>
<th style="text-align:left;width: 80%;"><strong>Digital Codes</strong></th>
<td><button class="btn btn-copy-code" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#group-1" style="display: none;"><span class="text-code">Copy Code</span></button></td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr><td style="text-align:left;width: 20%;">Xbox $5 Code</td><td style="text-align:left;width: 80%;" class="myCSS" ><span class="lic-key" id="group-2"  >BBBB-CCCC-AAAV</span><br></td><td><button class="btn btn-copy-code" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#group-2"><span class="text-code">Copy Code</span></button></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

And this should be your CSS

```
#myCSS{
border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
text-align: center;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 10px 8px; 
}
```

Comment: 1) You should include the CSS and HTML in the same snippet. 2) Your CSS appears to do nothing when I try to edit your post to have both in the same snippet. You don't appear to define the #myCSS ID anywhere in the HTML....

Comment: I said I cannot modify the html code. Sorry this is a bad answer.